# Adding img to div on load

Tags: jquery, onload

Is there a way to add a specific `img` to every element of class `.myClass` on its creation?

I tried this, and it doesn't work..

```
$('.myClass').live('load', function() {
    $(this).prepend('<img src="..." />');
});
```

My final goal is, to be able to create a modal box (or a light box) by just creating a `div` of class `myClass`, so I don't have to add the closing image tag (for closing the modal box) for each modal box

Comment: Only certain elements have a `load` event, images, scripts, etc.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your HTML code, and highlight exactly where you expect the code to be prepended. Also, does this add any code, anywhere?

Comment: If you're creating a `div` why not also prepend the `img` during creation of the `div`?  Why go through the overhead to watch events for created `div`s?

Comment: because i create the div by hand

Comment: @tamir - any luck with the livequery solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a better way than what i'm about to suggest, but i use [livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) to get that working. Livequery listen's for the moment the element appears in the DOM.

```
$('.myClass').livequery(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<img src="..." />');
});
```

If anyone knows of a better way, i'd love to see it too